# What animated film or TV show is this guy from?

Tags: character-identification

What animated film or tv show is this guy/pin from?

[image: The character is bald, with a fleshy face and large ears, wearing a matching yellow shirt and pants with a black vest, belt, gloves and boots. A large silver medallion hangs from a silver necklace.]

He has *1986* stamped on the back.

Comment: Can you show us the back also?

Comment: Looks like a Ferengi from Star Trek: Next Generation", but 1986 is about a year too early.

Comment: This is what you get when you order Yoda from Wish.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/s/ZWWo075FU9

Comment: https://twitter.com/MayorDasMoose/status/1727024141004681686

Comment: https://twitter.com/Losbennett/status/1727389507119378640

Comment: I think I've seen it on Heavy Metal: the movie, or something made by the same animators as that picture.

Comment: How is this science fiction or fantasy?

Comment: @user14111 - Because he looks like an alien. Or some sort of fantasy creature. Humans don't normally have ears like that.

Comment: @Valorum Back when people read newspapers you could find less human-looking caricatures on most any editorial page, but I wouldn't call them sci-fi or fantasy.

Comment: @user14111 - if he turns out not to be a scifi character we can easily close the question, but he looks sci-fi-y to me...

Comment: @Valorum Too bad we can't adopt the same sensible wait-and-see approach to story identification questions.

Comment: Looks like Han Solo to me

Comment: Star Wars: Droids was 1985–1986 and the animation style matches a bit, but I don't know the series well enough to say whether he's in it.

Comment: @shim i thought the same thing and combed up and down it, finding nothing